# I am getting this error when trying to run the Count(Subscriber) line of code: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error when I try to run this part `(Select Count(c.Subscriber_Id) From Contract Where c.Subscriber_id IN (Select s.Subscriber_id from Subscriber)) as Number_of_All_Contracts` from the below code. I'm not sure exactly how to resolve this. It gives me the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
Select Getdate() as Report_Run_Date, 
       s.Subscriber_id, 
       End_Dt as Contract_End_Date, 
       Eff_Date as Equipment_Eff_Dt, 
       MEID, 
       Name as Price_Plan_Name, 
       DATEDIFF(Month, Activation_Date, GetDate()) as Month_Subscriber_With_Company, 
       DATEDIFF(Day, GETDATE(), End_Dt) as Days_Until_Contract_End_Dt, 
       CASE WHEN End_Dt >= GETDATE() THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as In_Contract_Ind,
       (Select Count(c.Subscriber_Id) From Contract Where c.Subscriber_id IN (Select s.Subscriber_id from Subscriber)) as Number_of_All_Contracts
From Price_Plan p 
JOIN Subscriber s ON p.Price_Plan_Id = s.Price_Plan_Id
JOIN Contract c ON s.Subscriber_id = c.Subscriber_Id 
JOIN Equipment e ON c.Subscriber_Id = e.Subscriber_ID
Where s.status = 'Active' and s.Type = 'Postpaid' and p.Charge_Amt > 20
Group by s.subscriber_id, End_Dt, Eff_Date, MEID, Name, Activation_Date, c.Subscriber_Id;
```

Comment: are you sure this will give you the error? because i doubt that very much. Can you reproduce it in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43d4e99450c54da5933e327aac41f3fa

Comment: The problem is that you are referencing c.Subscriber_Id that is outside of this subquery. either remove the alias 'c' or use another alias in the subquery. Same issue in the IN (Select s.Subscriber_Id... the 's' is also referencing a table outside of the subquery. Fix both and you should be all set.

Comment: `count() over (partition by s.Subscriber_Id)`?

Comment: Hi nbk, I reproduced the code in dbfiddle.uk/... and it gave me the error: Msg 208 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
Invalid object name 'Price_Plan'.

Comment: Hi SS_DBA, I removed the aliases and re-ran the code which looks like this: '(Select Count(Subscriber_Id) From Contract Where Subscriber_id IN (Select Subscriber_id from Subscriber)) as Number_of_All_Contracts'  but I am getting the number of contracts equal to 8 contracts (all the contracts in the dataset) for each subscriber, but I think I should only be getting 2 contracts for subscriber_id #2, and 1 contract each for subscriber_id #3,5, and 7. I was able to get that code to work though.

Comment: Hi shawnt00, I was able to get the code to work by modifying your "count() over (partition by s.Subscriber_Id" code. I added c.Subscriber_id within the count function.

Comment: I'd be curious to see your working query.